# Why does text retrieved from pages sometimes look like gibberish?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urlopen

I'm using urllib and urllib2 in Python to open and read webpages but sometimes, the text I get is unreadable. For example, if I run this:

```
import urllib

text = urllib.urlopen('http://tagger.steve.museum/steve/object/141913').read()
print text
```

I get some unreadable text. I've read these posts:

[Gibberish from urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964726/gibberish-from-urlopen)

[Does python urllib2 automatically uncompress gzip data fetched from webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/dose-python-urllib2-will-automaticly-uncompress-gzip-data-from-fetch-webpage)

but can't seem to find my answer.

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

UPDATE: I fixed the problem by 'convincing' the server that my user-agent is a brower and not a crawler.

```
import urllib

class NewOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
  version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.120 Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2'

nop = NewOpener()
html_text = nop.open('http://tagger.steve.museum/steve/object/141913').read()
```

Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: The result of urlopen(youUrl) is a Javascript. Is this script really the content you want to get, or would like to get the actual content of the web page (what shows a browser) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to get the content. Download the server and client drivers, run server and run this:

```
from selenium import selenium
s = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://tagger.steve.museum")
s.start()

s.open("/steve/object/141913")

text = s.get_html_source()
print text
```

Comment: Thanks joshz! It turns out I will need Selenium because I need to execute the javascript before I'm able to view the page source the way you can see it in the browser. One quick question: If I run the above script on the interactive python interpreter, it works great. But if I store it in a file and run it all together it finds syntactic errors! Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Not really without knowing what error it is, I ran it from a file with Python 2.7.2. My best guess is when running from file it's with a different Python version.

Comment: It magically fixed itself! I have no idea what was causing the problem ! Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

This gibberish is a real server response for the request to `'http://tagger.steve.museum/steve/object/141913'`.  Actually, it looks like obfuscated JavaScript, which, if executed by a browser, loads page content.

To get this content, you need to execute this JavaScript, and this can be a really difficult task within Python. If you still want to do this, take a look at [`pywebkitgtk`](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/).