# How do i set a header that prevents the site from sending a gzip encoded response

Tags: python, http-headers, gzip, urlopen

i am using python urllib2.urlopen to get html content and i am getting a gziped response.
can i set the headers so i will get it not zipped ?

my code

```
response = urlopen(url,None , TIMEOUT)
html = response.read()  # read html
print html
```

as Tichodroma suggested i try this

```
request = Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'text/plain')
response = urlopen(request,None , TIMEOUT)
html = response.read().lower()  # read html
print html
```

now it is working

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/dose-python-urllib2-will-automaticly-uncompress-gzip-data-from-fetch-webpage

Comment: no its not a duplicate - i dont want to decompress it i want to get it not zipped in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Accept` header to the mime types you want to accept.

```
Accept: text/plain
```

if you like this :)

Comment: i needed to set request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'text/plain')