# No JSON object could be decoded when opening stackexchange api as json

Tags: python, json, stackexchange

I am accessing a particular url for a JSON file (fromt the stackexchange and stackoverflow api). While executing the `json.loads()` command it shows the following error:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=quant&pagesize=100&page=1"    
data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

<ipython-input-20-7540e91a8ff2> in <module>()
----> 1 data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    363 
    364         """
--> 365         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    366         end = _w(s, end).end()
    367         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    381             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    382         except StopIteration:
--> 383             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    384         return obj, end

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

On the other hand everything works fine with the twitter api... Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StackExchange API [always compresses its responses](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression), but Python [doesn't automatically uncompress it](http://bugs.python.org/issue1508475), so json is getting gzipped data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947241/434217) shows how to use the gzip module to handle the response.

Comment: Glad it helped. If that solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer (click the tick to the left).

Answer (score 6):

As @Thomas suggests it's because of [the gzip compression](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression).
I recommend using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library which worries about this kind of stuff for you:

```
import requests

data_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?page=1&pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=pandas&site=stackoverflow"
data_json = requests.get(data_url).json()
```