# Error using urllib2 to get torrent content from a url

Tags: python, urllib2

Python code:

```
    import urllib2
    import requests
    info_hash = '00001BD2C9F364C7DCB759DEC6BE02F913C96F72'
    url = 'http://torrage.com/torrent/%s.torrent' % info_hash
    print url
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read() # this data is err
    # data = requests.get(url).content # this data is ok
    f = open('%s.torrent' % info_hash, 'wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

I can't get right torrent content by the code, but I can get right torrent by the url in   browser.

Comment: Why not just use `requests` if it works?

Comment: well, at least it has an eight on [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1731881/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2), so we are not doing this for nothing.

Comment: @Cfreak yes, it works, but i want to konw:why urllib2 doesn't work(i use)? requests is another form of urllib2. thx

Comment: Without the error there's really not info for us to figure out. Could be a URL encoding problem which `requests` solves for you.

Comment: Or a redirect.. Can we have the exception, error codes, status codes and raw html?

Comment: try unzipping the response body:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-will-automaticly-uncompress-gzip-data-from-fetch-webpage