# python urllib2 returns garbage

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to download a web page with python and access some elements on the page. I have an issue when I download the page: the content is garbage. This is the first lines of the page:

```
‹í}évÛH²æïòSd±ÏmÉ·’¸–%ÕhµÕ%ÙjI¶«JããIÐ(‰îî{æ1æ÷¼Æ¼Í}’ù"à""’‚d÷t»N‰$–\"ãËˆŒˆŒÜøqïíîùï'û¬¼­gôÁnžm–úq<ü¹R¹¾¾._›å ìUôv»]¹¡gJÌqÃÍ’‡%z‹[ÎÖ3†[(,jüËÈ½Ú,í~ÌýX;y‰Ùò×f)æ7q…JzÉì¾F<ÞÅ]­Uª
```

this problem happen only on the following website: http://kickass.to. Is it possible that they have somehow protected their page? this is my python code:

```
import urllib2
import chardet
url = 'http://kickass.to/'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KH
TML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
f = open('page.html','w')
f.write(page)
f.close()
print response.headers['content-type']
print chardet.detect(page)
```

and result:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
{'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None}
```

it looks like an encoding issue but chardet detects 'None'.. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access the URL in your browser? I don't know about you but my ISP blocks that site. Maybe it is something to do with that?

Comment: @AlexThornton: Yes I can access it via the browser.

Comment: Wow, I have little experience with python 2, but maybe try `urllib`rather than `urllib2` for the sake of trying?

Comment: You might notice that `wget` fetches the same 'garbage' (actually sane, but gzipped) content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page is returned in `gzip` encoding.

(Try printing out `response.headers['content-encoding']` to verify this.)

Most likely the web-site doesn't respect 'Accept-Encoding' field in request and suggests that the client supports gzip (most modern browsers do).

`urllib2` doesn't support deflating, but you can use `gzip` module for that as described e.g. in this thread: [Does python urllib2 automatically uncompress gzip data fetched from webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-will-automaticly-uncompress-gzip-data-from-fetch-webpage) .

Comment: I already printed this out and got {'confidence': 0.0, 'encoding': None} back. Is it gzip then?

Comment: You've printed results of charset detection. I bet the charset detector doesn't expect gzip.
And yes, if you print 'content-encoding' from headers, you will see 'gzip'.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I though I had properly tested the gzip encoding before publishing the issue.. Cheers