# Extract javascript information from url with python

Tags: javascript, python, urllib2, urlopen

I have a URL that links to a javascript file, for example `http://something.com/../x.js`. I need to extract a variable from `x.js`

Is it possible to do this using python? 
At the moment I am using `urllib2.urlopen()` but when I use `.read()` I get this lovely mess:

```
U�(��%y�d�<�!���P��&Y��iX���O�������<Xy�CH{]^7e� �K�\�͌h��,U(9\ni�A ��2dp}�9���t�<M�M,u�N��h�bʄ�uV�\��0�A1��Q�.)�A��XNc��$"SkD�y����5�)�B�t9�):�^6��`(���d��hH=9D5wwK'�E�j%�]U~��0U�~ʻ��)�pj��aA�?;n�px`�r�/8<?;�t��z�{��n��W
�s�������h8����i�߸#}���}&�M�K�y��h�z�6,�Xc��!:'D|�s��,�g$�Y��H�T^#`r����f����tB��7��X�%�.X\��M9V[Z�Yl�LZ[ZM�F���`D�=ޘ5�A�0�){Ce�L*�k���������5����"�A��Y�}���t��X�(�O�̓�[�{���T�V��?:�s�i���ڶ�8m��6b��d$��j}��u�D&RL�[0>~x�jچ7�
```

When I look in the dev tools to see the DOM, the only thing in the body is a string wrapped in  tags. In the regular view that string is a json element.

Comment: Try opening the js file in the web browser, and see if it is indeed a js file

Comment: It certainly looks like one, it has one thing thing, a json variable with a lot of stuff in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.read()` should give you the same thing you see in the "view source" window of your browser, so something's wrong. It looks like the HTTP response might be gzipped, but **[`urllib2` doesn't support gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-automatically-uncompress-gzip-data-fetched-from-webpage)**. `urllib2` also doesn't request gzipped data, so if this is the problem, the server is probably misconfigured, but I'm assuming that's out of your control.

I suggest using **[`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/)** instead. `requests` [automatically decompresses gzip-encoded responses](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/), so it should solve this problem for you.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://something.com/x.js')
r.text   # unparsed json output, shouldn't be garbled
r.json() # parses json and returns a dictionary
```

In general, `requests` is much easier to use than `urllib2` so I suggest using it everywhere, unless you absolutely must stick to the standard library.

Comment: So its almost there. r.text gets me the string but r.json() fails with 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded' and r.text.json() fails with 'AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'json'
'

Comment: Any chance you could share the _actual_ url - it would make this much easier to troubleshoot!

Comment: Probably your URL returns JavaScript like `var data = {foo: "bar"}` rather than raw JSON. In that case, you'll need to do some string manipulation to get out the JSON before parsing it with `json.loads(s)`. That could be as simple as `s = r.text[s.find("{"):s.find("}")+1]`, if the JSON object is the first use of `{}` in the document, but it could be much more complex. JSON is also slightly stricter than actual JavaScript object notation — for example, you'll run into issues if the original JavaScript used `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

js = urllib2.urlopen("http://something.com/../x.js").read()
data = json.loads(js)
```

Comment: Sorry but no this gets me 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
'