# Decoding HTML output from urllib

Tags: python, decode

I'm trying to get an HTML output from a webpage.

```
data = response.read()
```

gives me something like that:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
```

How can I convert those characters into something like:

```
"<html><body>.."
```

?

Comment: i mean html code <  html> < body> and so on

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a [gzipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) response. You can verify this by checking the `Content-Encoding` response header, or writing the beginning of that byte sequence to a file and check its type with the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility if you're on a Unix-like platform:

```
>>> data =  '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> f = open('data.bin', 'w')
>>> f.write(data)
>>> f.close()
```

```
$ file data.bin
data.bin: gzip compressed data, last modified: Thu Jun 16 09:32:16 1994
```

You could [decode it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-automatically-uncompress-gzip-data-fetched-from-webpage), but I suggest ditching `urllib` for the [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module which [automatically decompresses it](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data):

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
print response.content
```

Comment: I think it should be `open('data.bin', 'wb')` so it accepts binary data. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @bvukelic that's true on Windows, I always forget about that... odd "feature". It doesn't make any difference though for any other platform. And since the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility doesn't exist on Windows (to my knowledge), it doesn't really make a difference in this case.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about that 'feature'. I just assumed it would be the same on all platforms since it's implied in the docs. I never thought of trying it without 'b' on Linux. https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: As far as I understand it's like this: There's no such thing as "binary data". There's just data. But for some reason, if you don't specify the binary mode, the Windows implementation of Python thinks it would be a hilarious idea to mess with newlines (feeding you different data than what's actually in the file, or writing something different from what you got in memory).