# Access data in Token protected API with python

Tags: python, web-services, api, http, curl

I have been trying to use python to get data from an API - which I am able to access manually like below

```
curl --location --compressed --header “Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]” [STREAM_URL]
```

How do I go about using it in python - I have read examples it says use `requests`but how to handle the Access_Token part in python

Any help would be appreciated?

Regards
VB

Comment: What do you mean by an "Authorized API"?

Comment: It expects a Access-Token every time I curl

Answer (score 0):

Just define your headers like you do in your curl example. In this case though, it's a dict. Assuming you want to use `requests` you would do something like this:

```
import requests

url = [STREAM_URL]
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer [ACCESS TOKEN]"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no different what to use. urllib come with the python and if you don't like to download additional package, use urllib.

As OP mentioned `--compressed` in curl command, we should do the same to get gzipped content:

Edited `ars` answer:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
  import urllib.request as urllib2
else:
  import urllib2

from StringIO import StringIO
import gzip

request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/')
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    buf = StringIO( response.read())
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
    data = f.read()
```

[Does python urllib2 automatically uncompress gzip data fetched from webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-automatically-uncompress-gzip-data-fetched-from-webpage)

Comment: I am getting a HTTP Error 406:Not acceptable error----

and I read that we need to append the header to the URL - how do I append my header to the URL -----

"<URL>?Authorization:Bearer [Token]"

Comment: try to checkout, what you really need. Headers couldn't be appended to url, but argument params could. You may need something like this: http://example.com/?authorization=xxxxxxxxxxx