# Having trouble converting JSON from youtube APIv3 to something I can work with in python

Tags: python, json, youtube-data-api

Right now I am just trying to print out the JSON through python. Eventually I will be using information from the requested JSON but I am stuck at just getting it into something I can work with.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import dateutil
import json

API_KEY = open("/Users/Sean/Documents/Yer.txt", "r")
API_KEY = API_KEY.read()

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUiufyZv8iRPTafTw0D4CvnQ&key='+API_KEY

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

videos = json.load(response)

print(videos)
```

This is where I started. I get the error

> the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

on the "videos = json.load(response)" line.

Searching around and ended up trying out

```
videos = json.load(response.decode())
```

With that I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\NeebsBot\NeebsBot\NeebsBot\NeebsBot.py", line 13, in 
>       videos = json.load(response.decode())
>   AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Searched again and tried this.

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

content = response.read()

videos = json.loads(content.decode('utf8'))

print(videos)
```

And I get this when I run

> 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 1573: character maps to

All the solutions I have found online always brings me back to these errors.

Comment: Show the beginning of content, but you could also try to decode it as ISO-8859-1 or Latin1 with `videos = json.loads(content.decode('latin1'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely receiving gzipped content, as a sample request to the Youtube API returned the following headers:

```
cache-control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  1706
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

You have two choices here, you can [add the snippet from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947241/790387) to decompress the content, or use the popular [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org) which takes care of all this for you.

In requests, your code would be:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(your_url_goes_here)
results = r.json()
print(results)
```

Comment: I get the same error "'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 725: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Ok I got this to work using a different IDE. I have been using Visual Studio 2015. I tried your solution out in pycharm and it works. Gotta love stuff like that, right?